# Why does my method run on its own?

Tags: java

I have a game code which builds a frame and sets it visible and stuff and it sets the `contentPane` to a `GamePanel` class I've created. This creates a `gamestatemanager` and from there it starts at state 0 or the Menu State. this is the code for the Menu State class. What keeps happening is before the menu is displayed, a popup box that is part of the `init()` of choice number 1 pops up like it has been selected using the enter key and `select()` method and I haven't been able to figure out why.

EDIT: I have forced a few errors to let the console give me the method calls in order and it's saying that as it initalizes GameStateManager, at the line where it is adding the DiceGameState(this) into the ArrayList it is initalizing the DiceGameState, which was the problem. Thank you for your help.

MenuState.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MenuState extends GameState {

private Background bg;

private int choice = 0;
private String[] options = { "Slot Machine", "Dice Toss", "Roulette Wheel", "Stats", "Leaderboards", "Quit" };

private Color titleColor;
private Font titleFont;

private Font font;

public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    this.gsm = gsm;
    try {
        bg = new Background("/Backgrounds/menubg.png", 1);
        bg.setVector(-0.1, 0);

        titleColor = Color.BLACK;
        titleFont = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
}

@Override
public void init() {
}

@Override
public void update() {
    bg.update();
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    // Draw BG
    bg.draw(g);

    // Draw title
    g.setColor(titleColor);
    g.setFont(titleFont);
    g.drawString("Jolly Jackpot Land!", 36, 60);

    g.setFont(font);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (i == choice)
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        else
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(options[i], 40, 130 + i * 15);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    g.drawString("v1.0.2.24.16 (c) Matthew Young", 165, 235);
}

private void select() {
    if (choice == 0) {
        // Slots
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.SLOTGAMESTATE);
    }
    if (choice == 1) {
        // Dice
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.DICEGAMESTATE);
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.ROULETTEGAMESTATE);
    }
    if (choice == 3) {
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.STATSTATE);
    }
    if (choice == 4) {
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.HELPSTATE);
    }
    if (choice == 5) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(int k) {
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        select();
    }
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        choice--;
        if (choice == -1) {
            choice = options.length - 1;
        }
    }
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        choice++;
        if (choice == options.length) {
            choice = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(int k) {
}
}
```

GameStateManager.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameStateManager {


private ArrayList<GameState> gameStates;
private int currentState;

public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
public static final int SLOTGAMESTATE = 1;
public static final int DICEGAMESTATE = 2;
public static final int ROULETTEGAMESTATE = 3;
public static final int STATSTATE = 4;
public static final int HELPSTATE = 5;

public GameStateManager() {
    gameStates = new ArrayList<GameState>();

    currentState = 0;
    gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));
    gameStates.add(new SlotGameState(this));
    gameStates.add(new DiceGameState(this));
    gameStates.add(new RouletteGameState(this));
    gameStates.add(new HelpState(this));
}

public void setState(int state){
    currentState = state;
    gameStates.get(currentState).init();
    currentState = 0;
}

public int getState() {
    return currentState;
}

public void update() {
    gameStates.get(currentState).init();
}

public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g){
    gameStates.get(currentState).draw(g);
}

public void keyPressed(int k){
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
}

public void keyReleased(int k) {
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think we have the information necessary to answer this. From where do you get `int choice`?

Comment: would it be possible to post more/all of your code? it would be much easier to trouble shoot if i can run your code.

Comment: its a lot of classes but yeah i can post some more hold on

Comment: the choice comes from your choice of option. so if option one in the menu is colored red and you press the down key, it changes option to 1, sets the 2 option in the displayed list to red and the other to white, and if you were to hit enter it would select choice 1 instead of choice 0

Comment: i still cannot see any problem with what you posted, can you also post Gamestate and also what uses MenuState. from what you mentioned something is messing with your choice. what else has access to choice?